# How can I change Hidden Value in Paypal Button

Tags: paypal

We are creating a simple sales site for local pickup no shipping, so in keeping it simple, we decided to use Vb.net and SQL Server, creating a catalog page and detail page with buying it now Paypal button. In using SQL server it will fill out the details page but we like it to be able to change the "value" in the following line :  . (the value is given when creating a button, but stored the value in SQL) Is there a simple solution

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="?????">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're asking how to dynamically render HTML with a value from your database? That's a straightforward web programming task, not a PayPal-specific question, any guide for your environment should cover it. Search for "asp.net output dynamic html" or similar

Comment: Maybe something like `<%:getButtonIdFromDatabase(); %>`

Comment: To be honest, I was looking at the fastest way to get it up and running, since Paypal gives a specific value for each item and pulls from the database to Insert Value="Paypal number". I didn't want a full-on cart until we see interest in the site.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this more, you're probably going around this the wrong way. There is no reason to store hosted button IDs in a database; such buttons exist for limited HTML-only websites.

Since your website is not limited to HTML, dispense with hosted buttons entirely and render buttons using a [standard PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/), which uses the JS SDK (and can optionally communicate with a backend to create and capture an order--see the full stack example in that guide, the backend routes of which can be implemented in whichever environment, .net in your case)

Comment: This is the best way forward, not the best at Java (as our colleagues at the time called it a dying language, with which other students like me disagreed at the time )

Comment: Java? I thought your backend was .net. But regardless of which backend you have or whether or not you even use one, the JS SDK in the guide above is easy to use and the best way forward. It does not redirect away from your site and gives a better experience than HTML-only buttons.